# Raspberry Pi 4 to PCA9685 Steering Working but not Throttle

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi 4 connecting to a PCA9685 and following the instruction on the donkeycar doc site (the link can be found below). I am at the step "fine tuning calibration." When I run "python manage.py drive" the steering works using my keyboard controls but the throttle is not causing any movement with the keys. I know that the throttle is not broken because the wheels turn when I do the calibration of the throttle. How do I solve this?

https://docs.donkeycar.com/guide/calibrate/

Answer (score 1):

There can be a few explanations for this:

1. Does your motor controller (ESC) have an on-off switch? If so, try flipping that
2. Some ESCs need to "arm". Try going to full throttle and back and see if that makes a difference
3. I'm assuming you have your battery plugged in ;-)
4. Try reversing the direction in the myconfig.py file

Comment: Hi Chris! I have the switch on so that is not the problem and I do have the battery plugged in! When I reach about .6 throttle on local host the car starts to beep, should I push past that point?

Comment: Looks like your calibration value is not correct. Try increasing `THROTTLE_STOPPED_PWM` and `THROTTLE_FORWARD_PWM`. When you have the right `THROTTLE_STOPPED_PWM` value, running `python manager.py drive` will produce a beep sound from the ESC

Comment: when I was calibrating, 370 was when the car beeped! what should I be trying to change it to?

Answer (score 0):

There was a [known bug](https://github.com/autorope/donkeycar/issues/989) in one version of DonkeyCar that could cause this problem.  That bug has been fixed, so I would update to the latest tagged version.  Open a console in your donkeycar project folder, then

```
git checkout $(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
git pull
pip3 install -e .[pi]
```

The fix involved changing how the drivetrain configuration was done, so you may need to update your mycar folder.  I tend to create a new one, then edit the myconfig.py file base on my older version.  The many of the drivetrain configurations changed from being a set of constants to a python dictionary, so you need to uncomment the appropriate dictionary.  So if your drivetrain in myconfig.py is

```
DRIVE_TRAIN_TYPE = "PWM_STEERING_THROTTLE"
```

Then you want to uncomment the following lines in myconfig.py and update the values with your pin connections and calibration values.

```
PWM_STEERING_THROTTLE = {
"PWM_STEERING_PIN": "PCA9685.1:40.1",   # PWM output pin for steering servo
"PWM_STEERING_SCALE": 1.0,              # used to compensate for PWM frequency differents from 60hz; NOT for adjusting steering range
"PWM_STEERING_INVERTED": False,         # True if hardware requires an inverted PWM pulse
"PWM_THROTTLE_PIN": "PCA9685.1:40.0",   # PWM output pin for ESC
"PWM_THROTTLE_SCALE": 1.0,              # used to compensate for PWM frequence differences from 60hz; NOT for increasing/limiting speed
"PWM_THROTTLE_INVERTED": False,         # True if hardware requires an inverted PWM pulse
"STEERING_LEFT_PWM": 460,               #pwm value for full left steering
"STEERING_RIGHT_PWM": 290,              #pwm value for full right steering
"THROTTLE_FORWARD_PWM": 500,            #pwm value for max forward throttle
"THROTTLE_STOPPED_PWM": 370,            #pwm value for no movement
"THROTTLE_REVERSE_PWM": 220,            #pwm value for max reverse throttle
}
```